# Hibernate Validation and localized error messages?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

hibernate and i want to provide localized error messages for hibernate annotations
so i created to properties files ValidatorMessages.properties, ValidatorMessages_ar.properties

and put them in resources folder, and i am using messageSource to read from property files:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messages</value>
                <value>classpath:errors</value>
                <value>classpath:app</value>
                <value>classpath:ValidatorMessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

and in the class i use something like:

```
@NotNull(message = "{validation.notEmpty.password}")
private string password;
```

and when calling the validator i use:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
                .getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<MyClass> cvs = validator
                .validate(myObject);
        for (ConstraintViolation<MyClass> cv : cvs) {
            String field = cv.getPropertyPath().toString();
            result.addError(new FieldError("version", field, cv.getMessage()));
        }

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            initModel();
            result.reject("add.version.errors");
            return "manageVersions";
        }
```

it works fine with english, it displays english messages correctly, but when switching to arabic it still displays the english messages instead of arabic, although that

`LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` indicates that the language is changed and it's arabic, so is there are something missing with the configuration or any ideas what might cause that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Spring config when you are setting up your validator bean, I think you need to set the message interpolator:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageInterpolator" ref="interpolator" />
</bean>
```

where the interpolator bean would be of type LocaleContextMessageInterpolator (see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocaleContextMessageInterpolator.html) for more info).  Hibernate Validator doesn't automatically know to look at LocaleContextHolder.

You might also need to set validationMessageSource property but I think its defaulted properly since you are at least getting the English error messages.

Comment: I guess this answer is more appropriate – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225023/messageinterpolator-in-spring#11226683.