# MessageInterpolator in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

I use Spring 3.1.1 and Hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final and have a problem with changing default MessageInterpolator, which takes validation messages from ValidationMessages (in classpath).

I wanna use ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator which will take messages from my spring messageSource

I did something like this in my application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="resourceBundleMessageInterpolator"
      class="org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="messageSource"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageInterpolator" ref="resourceBundleMessageInterpolator"/>
</bean>
```

And when I start my web application in logs I see:

```
11:04:07,402 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl] - 
Setting custom MessageInterpolator of type
 org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator 
11:04:07,402 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl] - 
Setting custom ConstraintValidatorFactory of type org.springframework .validation.beanvalidation.SpringConstraintValidatorFactory
```

So as you can see, it's not ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator which i want. It's LocaleContextMessageInterpolator

Later when I try to validate something I just get the messages from ValidationMessages.properties, not from spring message source:

```
11:08:09,397 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator] - 
ValidationMessages not found.
11:08:09,413 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator] - 
org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found.
```

As you can see from application-context.xml I wanna use MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator, but it's used, I don't know why PlatformResourceBundleLocator

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't have to declare `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator` and `MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator` beans by yourself (unless you have to), they are created by `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` when you supply `messageSource`:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
 </bean>
```

(It does this under the hood:)

```
public void setValidationMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageInterpolator = HibernateValidatorDelegate.buildMessageInterpolator(messageSource);
}

// (...)


private static class HibernateValidatorDelegate {

    public static MessageInterpolator buildMessageInterpolator(MessageSource messageSource) {
        return new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(new MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator(messageSource));
    }
}
```

So with simplified bean definition, do you get same debug output? Where do you use "validator" ref? You may have to use `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">` for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Earlier I used, simpler version with setValidationMessageSource, as you wrote. The behavior was the same as I described at first. The matter is that I missed an attribute validator="validator" in my <mvc:annotation-driven/>. I added the attribute and it works.

Comment: what to do if I use spring-web module only, not spring-webmvc?

Comment: where to use validator ref in annotation based configuration

Comment: @karthi Ask new question with your specific problem.