# Spring Data REST(using Spring Boot) - Hibernate Validation Localization

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, localization, spring-data-rest

I am currently evaluating [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/).
I started with this simple example: [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

It works out of the box. But now, in the next step, I wanted to try some validation to see how the framework reacts. So I simply annotated the `Person`class:

```
@Size(min = 2, message = "{test.error.message}")
private String firstName;
```

The validation itself is working, I get an error message. The message is resolved if I put a file called `ValidationMessages.properties` in the root of the classpath (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html) why).

---

Now, instead of having the files in the root I wanted to place them in a subfolder (e.g. `lang/ValidationMessages.properties`) and use Spring `MessageSource` instead of the default approach.

After some research I found the following question:
[MessageInterpolator in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225023/messageinterpolator-in-spring#11226683)

Unfortunately using the following bean definitions does not work:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

  <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <list>
        <value>lang/ValidationMessages</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="validator"
            class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The corresponding dependencies inside the pom.xml (just in case):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

Does anyone know what I am missing? Could it be due to the fact that I am not using Spring MVC but Spring Data REST? If yes, is there a way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some additional investigation (and a lot of searching) I found a solution to the issue.

---

**PROBLEM**

Hibernate does **not use beans for the validator factory**, thats why the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` is not used.

*For more details look into `org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator#activate(ActivationContext activationContext)`*

---

**FIRST APPROACH**

You can actually specify which factory to use by using this property:  **`javax.persistence.validation.factory`**

**Unfortunately this can't be used (yet) inside Spring Boot's `application.properties`.**
*(see this [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2808))*

---

**SOLUTION**

Using the workaround described in the linked GitHub issue works.
You have to provide a configuration for Hibernate:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig extends HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private ValidatorFactory validator;

  @Override
  protected void customizeVendorProperties(Map<String, Object>     vendorProperties) {
    super.customizeVendorProperties(vendorProperties);
    vendorProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
  }
}
```

Using this approach the messages get resolved correctly.

Answer (score 3):

HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration can not work anymore (after sprint boot 2.10)

You can do like this if you are using Spring Boot 2.1.0+:

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
class SpringValidatorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(final Validator validator) {
        return new HibernatePropertiesCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
                hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The idea from  [Spring Boot 2.0.0 M6 - Add Hibernate Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465728/spring-boot-2-0-0-m6-add-hibernate-interceptor/48207856#48207856)

and [Spring Boot - Hibernate custom constraint doesn't inject Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212117/spring-boot-hibernate-custom-constraint-doesnt-inject-service/50213178#50213178)