# Spring Boot 2.0.0 M6 - Add Hibernate Interceptor

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, interceptor

After upgrade from Spring Boot 2.0.0 M2 to 2.0.0 M6 my Hibernate interceptor implementation don't work anymore.

My old implementation:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration extends HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration {

    private HibernateStatisticsInterceptor hibernateStatisticsInterceptor;

    public HibernateConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties jpaProperties, ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager, ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers, ObjectProvider<List<SchemaManagementProvider>> providers, HibernateStatisticsInterceptor hibernateStatisticsInterceptor) {
        super(dataSource, jpaProperties, jtaTransactionManager, transactionManagerCustomizers, providers);
        this.hibernateStatisticsInterceptor = hibernateStatisticsInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeVendorProperties(Map<String, Object> vendorProperties) {
        vendorProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", hibernateStatisticsInterceptor);
    }
}
```

But with M5 or M6 the HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration class changed and extends JpaBaseConfiguration no more.

I try to add my interceptor per YAML-Configuration file, but it's not working.

My Interceptor:

```
@Component("hibernateStatisticsInterceptor")
public class HibernateStatisticsInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5278832720227796822L;

    private ThreadLocal<Long> queryCount = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void startCounter() {
        queryCount.set(0l);
    }

    public Long getQueryCount() {
        return queryCount.get();
    }

    public void clearCounter() {
        queryCount.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        Long count = queryCount.get();
        if (count != null) {
            queryCount.set(count + 1);
        }
        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }

}
```

How can I reactivate my interceptor?

Thanks for any hints

regards
Rizzi

Comment: Can you try to extend from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.java instead of HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration?

Comment: This is not a public class and can't use outside it's package :/

Comment: After some more research I find a way to add my Hibernate interceptor.

You can add an interceptor by properties/yml file, but I try the wrong place first.

It should be 
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.interceptor = <class with path>`

My new Problem is, that this hibernate creates his own instance of this class and is different to my instance from spring :/

regards
Rizzi

Answer (score 7):

I can solve this with this documentation:

[Add support for advanced customization of Hibernate settings](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/59d5ed58428d8cb6c6d9fb723d0e334fe3e7d9be)

Just implements a interface *HibernatePropertiesCustomizer*

and implements methods *customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties)*

```html
@Component
class MyHibernateInterceptorCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    MyInterceptor myInterceptor

    @Override
    void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
       hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", myInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Hello**,

Give this a read: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/59d5ed58428d8cb6c6d9fb723d0e334fe3e7d9be (use: HibernatePropertiesCustomizer interface)

1. Implement it.
2. **@Override customize() method**, add your interceptor
3. Don't forget to **@Lazy inject** in case of internal beans
4. Done => Run

Hope this was of use to you.

As a final note: **always update your Spring / Hibernate versions** (use the latest as possible) and you will see that most code will become redundant as newer versions try to reduce the configurations as much as possible.

Comment: The `@Lazy` is the trick to get it done while autowiring `repositories` to the Interceptor. Thank you, you just saved my time.

Answer (score 4):

As https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11211 has been resolved, `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` can be used since Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 (not released at the moment of writing yet but snapshots are available now).