# Null pointer exception on autowired field in Hibernate Interceptor (classes are managed by Spring)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I use Spring Boot and Hibernate in my application and I get NPE trying to reach a service in my Hibernate interceptor. I don't have any troubles injecting this comment service in other classes.
What is wrong?

The service I need:

```
@Service
public class CommentServiceImpl implements CommentService {

    private CommentRepository commentRepository;

    private TargetTypeRepository targetTypeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CommentServiceImpl(final CommentRepository commentRepository, final TargetTypeRepository targetTypeRepository) {
        this.commentRepository = commentRepository;
        this.targetTypeRepository = targetTypeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Comment> getComments(String targetType, Long targetId) {
        TargetType targetTypeEntity = targetTypeRepository.findByCode(targetType);
        return commentRepository.findByTargetTypeAndTargetId(targetTypeEntity, targetId);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteComments(String targetType, Long targetId) {
        List<Comment> comments = getComments(targetType, targetId);
        commentRepository.deleteAll(comments);
    }
}
```

The interceptor:

```
@Component
public class MvaSupportInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private CommentService commentService;

    @Override
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
    {
        if (entity instanceof DraftDoc)
        {
            commentService.deleteComments("DRAFT_DOC", ((DraftDoc)entity).getId()); //NPE
        }
        super.onDelete(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
}
```

The configuration is just like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

P.S. When I try to inject the comment service via constructor I get this:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2021-09-06 14:18:47.628
> ERROR [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
> [826] : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException:
> Could not instantiate named strategy class
> [com.cbr.mva.interceptors.MvaSupportInterceptor]  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
> at com.cbr.mva.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:22) Caused
> by:
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException:
> Could not instantiate named strategy class
> [com.cbr.mva.interceptors.MvaSupportInterceptor]  at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:220)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:160)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:147)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:141)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.determineInterceptor(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:553)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:301)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:49)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImpl.java:149)
> at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
> ... 16 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException:
> Could not instantiate named strategy class
> [com.cbr.mva.interceptors.MvaSupportInterceptor]  at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.lambda$static$0(StrategySelectorImpl.java:40)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:216)
> ... 31 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> com.cbr.mva.interceptors.MvaSupportInterceptor    at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:571)     at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.lambda$static$0(StrategySelectorImpl.java:36)
> ... 32 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> com.cbr.mva.interceptors.MvaSupportInterceptor.init()     at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)     ... 33 common
> frames omitted

Just in case, NPE stack trace:

> 2021-09-06 14:24:20.343 ERROR [nio-8090-exec-2]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]     [175] : Servlet.service()
> for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw
> exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
> com.cbr.mva.interceptors.MvaSupportInterceptor.onDelete(MvaSupportInterceptor.java:33)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:274)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:159)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:72)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:886)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:818)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.remove(SessionImpl.java:3280)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.remove(Unknown Source)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.remove(Unknown Source)   at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete(SimpleJpaRepository.java:203)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.deleteById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:175)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy219.deleteById(Unknown Source)   at
> com.cbr.mva.service.impl.DocServiceImpl.deleteDocument(DocServiceImpl.java:99)
> at
> com.cbr.mva.service.impl.DocServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$884ab214.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
> at
> com.cbr.mva.service.impl.DocServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3028e824.deleteDocument()
> at
> com.cbr.mva.controller.DocumentController.delete(DocumentController.java:70)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:666)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Comment: Can you show the full stack traces?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: Are `CommentRepository` and `TargetTypeRepository` components?

Comment: Yes, they marked by @Repository annotation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Spring managed Hibernate interceptors in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I saw this question and it was quite useful, it made my interceptor actually work. But it still does not resolve this NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in a way of registering my interceptor:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=my.package.MyInterceptorClassName.
```

It didn't allow to use beans inside the interceptor.

Suggested way didn't work for me since my Spring Boot version is 2.2: 
[How to use Spring managed Hibernate interceptors in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot)

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration extends HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration{


    @Autowired
    Interceptor userInterceptor;


    @Override
    protected void customizeVendorProperties(Map<String, Object> vendorProperties) {
        vendorProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor",userInterceptor);
    }
}
```

But I found the answer here: 
[Spring Boot 2.0.0 M6 - Add Hibernate Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465728/spring-boot-2-0-0-m6-add-hibernate-interceptor/48207856#48207856)

```
@Component
class MyHibernateInterceptorCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    MyInterceptor myInterceptor

    @Override
    void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
       hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", myInterceptor);
    }
}
```

> Use: HibernatePropertiesCustomizer interface
>
> 1.Implement it. 
> 2.Override customize() method, add your interceptor 
> 3.Don't forget to @Lazy inject in case of internal beans